# Connecting a Hardware wallet to a full node

Tags: json-rpc, full-node, wallet-security

I'm trying to connect my hardware wallet to my personal full node for the sake of privacy. I need to know the node's IP, port, and RPC credentials. The first two are easy, I can see my full node in bitcodes.io that's up and running. I added the

```
rpcuser=xxx
rpcpassword=****
```

to the bitcoin.conf file. But When I try to connect through my hardware wallet application, it says: *The node is not reachable.* I'm not sure whether the bitcoind is reading the rpc inputs from the config file or not. Is there anyway that I could try to reach to my node to make sure it's reachable using the rpc credentials.

Here is the content in the bitcoin.conf file:

```
prune=0
txindex=1
server=1
daemon=1
rpcuser=letsbegin
rpcpassword=*****
externalip=xx.xx.xx.xx
```

Comment: What hardware wallet software?

Comment: It's the Ledger Live

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to connect your hardware wallet to a full node depends heavily on what wallet software you're using. But assuming your software connects to a full node via the bitcoind RPC interface:

By default, the RPC listener only listens on localhost. If you want to connect to the RPC service from another computer, you'll have to allow other connections by including these lines in your bitcoin.conf (replace:

```
server=1
rpcallowip=<add the IP you are connecting from here, or rpcallowip=* to allow all IPs>
rpcport=8332
```

If you want to simply test whether your bitcoind RPC is accessible, you can simply make an HTTP request to the RPC host at port 8332 from the computer you're trying to connect from.

Comment: So, here is the issue: Both the connecting computer and my node are within the same network i.e., same IP address! I added the commands that you suggested, still I can't reach to my node even when I make an HTTP request!!!

Comment: By same network do you mean same computer? If so, then make sure you use "127.0.0.1:8332".

Comment: No not the same computer. Two different computers connected to the internet at my home. When I run the get networkinfo command:"name": "ipv4",
      "limited": false,
      "reachable": true,
      "proxy": "",
      "proxy_randomize_credentials": false
    },
    {
      "name": "ipv6",
      "limited": false,
      "reachable": true,
      "proxy": "",
      "proxy_randomize_credentials": false
    },
    {
      "name": "onion",
      "limited": true,
      "reachable": false,
      "proxy": "",
      "proxy_randomize_credentials": false

Comment: When I check the external ip address for both the computers I get the same ip! Should I use internal IP address assigned to my node?

Comment: @Pishi - yes, use the internal IPs for this.

Comment: I still have the issue of not being able to connect to my node. Even when I enter the local IP address for my node in a browser with the port (8332) still I can't connect. Do you think it's a firewall thing imposed by the Ubuntu running on my node? The node is running on a static IP with the port forwarded in my router. The node currently has 55 connections and roughly sends 10G of data daily!!

Comment: Did you add the line `rpcallowip=<the local IP address of the computer you're connecting from>`?

Comment: Yes, I added and for the IP I added the external IP and the Internal IP but none worked.